# Yii Framework - How to include JavaScript without register

Tags: php, yii

I'm registering a script when a form is created:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(
    Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/activity_package.js',
    CClientScript::POS_END
);
```

But I need to call `renderPartial()` when some records are created dynamically in the view, and it does the script load two or more times. How can I include my script so that there's certainty that it's loaded only one time?

Comment: Load it in the main view not on the `renderPartial()` view.

Comment: I'm calling `registerScriptFile()` from the controller, before the main view is rendered.

Comment: When you are adding records dynamically are you using an ajax call to the same controller/action?

Comment: @Pitchinnate Yes, the same controller, but different action. Must I use another controller? Isn't there a more flexible way?

Comment: Is the script registered inside the action function or just in the controller? I personally never register script files in the controller I have always done it in the view, I've never had this issue.

Comment: It's fine, @Pitchinnate. I put it in the main view and it worked. If you want, write an answer for it and I'll accept. Thank you.

Comment: No. It's still not working. Sorry! When `processOutput` is true -- I need it to get the client validation code --, the same registered script is still being loaded.

Comment: Create var where you will store flag that script is loaded. Each time check it. For example create class loader, that will register for you this script if it wasn't registered yet. Also you can add there any logic you need, filter for ajax etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ajax requtest with renderpartial() so you have to check if the app has not ajax request so register scripts:

```
if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
      $this->renderPartial('myView',array('data'=>$data),false,true);
}else{
      Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('myscript','script');
}
```

Comment: `Yii::clientScript()` doesn't exist. Right? Did you mean `registerClientScript()`?

Comment: Sorry I edited the code I mean Yii::app()->clientScript